# Visual Studio 2015 Debug and Continue

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

We changed our environment from Visual Studio 2008 to 2015 (Update 1) and now we got some strange debug behaviors.

When we hit a breakpoint and change some code and continue, we are not able to see the variable content of some types in the quick watch or immediate window anymore. (e.g. DataTables, Images ...)

```
A type or generic instantiation needed to evaluate this expression does not exist in the process of being debugged
```

Our target framework is .NET 3.5. When we change it to 4.0 or higher everything works fine.
At the moment we are not able to change to 4.0.

It is not a project related problem. We can reproduce it with a simple 'Hello World' console application.

Does someone have any idea how to solve this problem ?